# Matrix Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Let $A$ and $T$ be $n$ by $n$ nonsingular matrices. Suppose we are given $L$ and $ U$, which are lower and upper triangular respectively, and that $TA = LU$. How can this be used to solve $Ax = b$, for any $x$ and any given $b$.

I'm not really sure how to approach this. I known I need to use backwards and forwards substitution, but I'm not sure how exactly to do this.

Comment: If $A$ and $T$ are nonsingular, what is $x$ going to be in $Ax = b$? Furthermore, if $TA = LU$, what do you know about $A$?

Comment: You don't know anything about $A$. $x$ is an arbitrary vector and $b $ is any given vector.

Comment: $A$ is nonsingular, no? So if $A$ is nonsingular, what do you know about $A$?

Comment: The determinant of $A$ is nonzero and $A $ is invertible. How does this help?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible and $Ax = b$, you can easily solve for $x$...

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to multiply both sides of the equation by $T$, thus getting
$$TAx = Tb = LUx,$$ thanks to the assumption $TA = LU$. Let us call $y:= Ux$ and $b_0 := Tb$. We then find $Ly = b_0$, which can be solved efficiently with forward substitution to find $y$ (remember that since $T$ and $b$ are given also $b_0$ is given). You can then solve  $Ux = y$ using backward substitution to retrieve $x$.

This is the standard method for solving linear systems when the LU decomposition of the matrix is known. The complexity of the solution of the triangular linear systems is $n^2$ and the complexity of the multiplication matrix-vector is $n^2$ as well. In general, the complexity for solving $Ax=b$ (which depends on the algorithm you use) is likely to be higher than $n^2$.

Comment: @ lupod , say why your method has a better complexity than directly solving $Ax=b$.

Comment: This is the standard method for solving linear systems when the LU decomposition of the matrix is known. The complexity of the solution of the triangular linear systems is $n^2$ and the complexity of the multiplication matrix-vector is $n^2$ as well. In general, the complexity for solving $Ax = b$ (which depends on the algorithm you use) is likely to be higher than $n^2$.

Comment: @ lupod , yes. You can copy your comment as an edit of your answer.